# Unexpected error in Pusher private channel subscription

Tags: javascript, php, pusher, subscribe

In JS+PHP (homestead) environment, subscribing to public channel in Pusher works fine (also validates my credentials). Subscribing to private channel fails, given following code:

```
 let theAppId = 'XXXYYYZZZ'; //fake credentials shown here...
 pusher = new Pusher(theAppId, {
    authEndpoint: '/pusher/auth',
    cluster: 'us2',
    forceTLS: true,
    encrypted: true,
    auth: {headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': self.csrf}}
});
channel = pusher.subscribe('private-channel1');
```

My auth code is called and returns a valid auth sig:

```
{\"auth\":\"c289b20c368bd23a4a85:d55f1f1495f0d252b5fde1d69e2e6d5b4b161ca49cab5ad218d65111ae307a12\"}"}
```

After successful connection, Pusher.log shows this error:

```
Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher:error","data":{"code":null,"message":"Invalid key in subscription auth data: '{\"auth\"'"}}
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":null,"message":"Invalid key in subscription auth data: '{\"auth\"'"}}}
```

I can't find any mention of this problem in the Pusher docs. Anyone seen this, or have ideas on how to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause of this error is that the `auth` hash was "stringified" before it was returned from the server. That's why the error message mentions that an *invalid key* was found: the value couldn't be parsed as a JSON object.

To fix this issue, the server needs to return plain JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Hosam for the hint. The problem for you Laravel users, is easy to fix. Note that the response from your auth route is json. The value returned to create a valid auth key from `pusher->socket_auth` is a json-encoded string. To solve this problem, just `json_decode` the `socket_auth` response to an associative array, then pass that in your controller json response:

```
$thePusher = new \Pusher\Pusher(
   env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
      ['cluster'=>env('PUSHER_CLUSTER'),'useTLS'=>true]
);

$theResult=$thePusher->socket_auth(
   $aRequest>input('channel_name'),
   $aRequest->input('socket_id'));

return response()->json(json_decode($theResult,true),200);
```

Comment: To avoid decoding and re-encoding of JSON, we can
`return response($theResult, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');`